# pip3 command is always killed with error code 9 in my M1 MacBook Pro

Tags: python, pip, apple-m1

I migrated from my old MacBook Pro to a new M1 MacBook Pro.

There is a package I want to uninstall with pip3 but when I run `pip3 uninstall thePackageName`, I always get `Killed: 9`.

In my own research, error code 9 is [SIGKILL](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html): abnormal termination of the process.

But I don't know what exactly is a problem here. Has anyone encountered a similar issue? Any idea what the problem is here?